# Laravel:: Routing issue with Twilio

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twilio

New to the laravel community so thank you for any help.

**Issue**:
I have the following route to controller `Route::get('itr', 'ItrController@receive');`

My controller

```
public function receive()
    {
        $response = Response::make('<Response><Sms>Got it!</Sms></Response>');

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        return $response;
}`
```

I can navigate to the url, no problem, renders the xml as desired. However, when trying to access from Twilio messaging URL with http://demo.myurl.com/itr, i get 404 response. Tested outside laravel, twilio responds accordingly, inside laravel, I get the 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio sends POST requests, not GET requests. Make your route a POST route and it'll work fine:

```
Route::post('itr', 'ItrController@receive');
```

Comment: @Bungdaddy I've done it a half dozen times myself. :-)

Comment: Twilio Evangelist here - just to add that you can actually change the HTTP method for most Twilio requests. Either through the REST API, or the user interface. See: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers, you can set the `sms_method` to `GET` or `POST`. Or login to Twilio and change on the Number page.